# JBoss_Keycloak_"404 - Not Found"

Tags: jboss, single-sign-on, keycloak, web.xml, wildfly-11

I am stuck with a JBoss-Keycloak issue. Posting this with the hope that someone who has encountered this may have some idea on what could be going wrong. Details are below.

Environment -

1. OS -

```
  $ sw_vers
  ProductName: Mac OS X
  ProductVersion: 10.14.5
  BuildVersion: 18F132
```

2. JBoss EAP 7.1 - running with adapter and on localhost:8080 with hello.war deployed
3. Keycloak 7.0.1 - running on localhost:8180

Issue -

. Getting "404 - Not Found" for a simple hello.war (with KEYCLOAK as the auth-method in its web.xml ; keycloak.json lies beside web.xml) when accessing http://localhost:8080/hello

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-12776

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by making the module name in web.xml match the webapp name (hello) ...

```
<module-name>hello</module-name>
```